# How can I return the number of elements before a debounce timeout

Tags: rx-java, reactive-programming

I would like to create an Observer in Java that works kind of like debounce in that it waits for the specified timeout before emitting.

However instead of returning the last element like debounce does, I would like it to return the full list of events that were generated during that time.

I've been playing with buffer and window, but those take a snapshot every fixed interval. I want it to rather take the snapshot after a specified pause duration.

Comment: i am not sure but have you tried with throttleLast instead of debounce?

Comment: There are overloads to buffer and window where you can use other Observables to indicate buffer boundaries.

Comment: @SanketKachhela  throttleLast is a synonym for debounce.

Comment: throttlelast will emit event at every X seconds where debounce will only emit event if X seconds has passed without emitting it. here is article for it. https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-throttling-and-debouncing/